# How do I set up a Link Aggregation for 2 ports between a Sonicwall TZ500 and a Dell XP1018P

Tags: routing, switching, sonicwall, dell

A LAG group on the X1018P managed switch is real easy but switch port configuration is not available on the TZ 500.  Is there a way to set it up for 2 ports like x0 and x2 on the firewall and e15 and e16 on the switch?  How would I configure the firewall ports?  Is this a PortShield Group????

Comment: KorXo is correct, you can't do this on the TZ series (only higher end NSA and NSA E-Class allows link aggregation). I just wanted to add: a PortShield group joins 2 or more ports into a logical bridge (switch) that act the same -- so instead of X0 and X2 being separate interfaces if they are in a PortShield they are the same (X2 is "linked" to X0 as if connected to the same 'switch' internally).

Comment: This article implies that it can be done, naming the TZ Series in the "categories" section. I don't have the link aggregation choice in the named drop-down, however.

Comment: And this article says it's available on Gen 6 devices. But I don't have the drop-down mentioned.  https://www.sonicwall.com/en-us/support/knowledge-base/170505763142649

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it on Sonicwall device. TZ series doesn't support link aggregation. Check this doc http://documents.software.dell.com/sonicos/6.2.3.1/release-notes/document-download?ParentProduct=847

Answer (score 0):

the only way is to add a 3rd switch with a trunk connecting the other 2 switches with their trunks and the third switch port 16 to the sonicwall Tz500 and creating the vlans on it